# Cannot create annotated git tag from groovy script

Tags: groovy

Using:

```
Groovy Version: 3.0.8 JVM: 11.0.10 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

I have this script:

```
def shellCommand(String cmd) {

  def process = cmd.execute()
  def output = new StringWriter(), error = new StringWriter()
  process.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
  println "exit value=${process.exitValue()}"
  println "OUT: $output"
  println "ERR: $error"

}

def gitRelease() {
    def cmd001 = "git tag -a -m \"Release 0.0.777\" 0.0.45"
    shellCommand(cmd001)
}

gitRelease()
```

When I run it from command line I get below error:

```
$ groovy myScript.groovy
exit value=128
OUT: 
ERR: fatal: Failed to resolve '0.0.45' as a valid ref.
```

Same error if I try with *slashy* string:

```
def cmd001 = /git tag -a -m "Release 0.0.777" 0.0.45/
```

If I instead run git directly it works:

```
$ git tag -a -m "Release 0.0.777" 0.0.45
$ git tag
0.0.45
```

Creating a simple tag from the above groovy script works:

```
def gitRelease() {
    //def cmd001 = "git tag -a -m \"Release 0.0.777\" 0.0.45"
    def cmd001 = "git tag 0.0.46" 
    shellCommand(cmd001)
}
```

gives:

```
$ groovy myScript.groovy
exit value=0
OUT: 
ERR:
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try the `List` form of execute() instead of the String? `def cmd1 = ["git", "tag", "-a", "-m", "Release 0.0.777", "0.0.45"]`

Comment: Thanks that was it! Seems I was hitting the "Gotcha" described here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/90802207847/

Comment: Cool!  Posted as an answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String.execute method often gives issues in unexpected places

There's another List.execute method that gives much more expected results

```
def cmd1 = ["git", "tag", "-a", "-m", "Release 0.0.777", "0.0.45"]
```

You should also change

```
def shellCommand(String cmd) {
```

To

```
def shellCommand(List cmd) {
```